# Convert datetime to string and display like 'yyyy_MM' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hello everyone I'm using

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, i.createdDate, 120)
```

to convert to `varchar`.

What should I do to display the date as `yyyy_MM` like this?:

```
'2012-12-16 14:50:00' to '2012_12'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server? SQL Server 2012 has a new `FORMAT()` function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), GETDATE(), 120), '-', '_')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this SQL Server 2012? You can use the FORMAT function.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505%28SQL.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, didn't see.  Please see my other answer, if it's SQL Server 2012.

Comment: It would have been better if you just edit your current question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(GETDATE())) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(m, GETDATE()))
```